# Is it possible to simplify __repr__ display only when it displays in List?

Tags: python

say I have a defined object:

```
class Job(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{name}>".format(name=self.name)
```

When I'm calling in REPL like ipython:

```
>>job=Job('Job BUILD - test - 20130226000000_20130227000000 - GMT+08:00 2020-04-24 21:48:15')
Job BUILD - test - 20130226000000_20130227000000 - GMT+08:00 2020-04-24 21:48:15
```

the REPL would display its name. it looks OK for me if only one object is displaying on the console.

While there could be sometimes that the job objects display in a List, Like:

```
[<Job BUILD - test - 20130226000000_20130227000000 - GMT+08:00 2020-04-24 21:48:15>,
 <Job BUILD - test - 20130226000000_20130227000000 - GMT+08:00 2020-04-24 17:45:58>,
 <Job BUILD - test - 20130225000000_20130226000000 - GMT+08:00 2020-04-24 17:44:49>]
```

This looks disgraceful, is there any idea to shorten the **repr** only when the object's displaying in list.

Comment: No, the `__repr__` will be used in both cases

Comment: alright, or any workaround? I want it to print the whole name of the object when a single Job returned, but not in list.

Comment: Either write your own list wrapper with the `__repr__` you want, *don't* rely on the `__repr__` (e.g. `print([job.name[:20] for job in job_list])` instead), or tolerate it.

Comment: hmm it's too hardcore, I'd rather tolerate it. Thanks for your reply :)